# Return data from SWR mutate after login

Tags: reactjs, laravel, next.js, swr

I have nextJS application with Laravel backend, and I am trying to use [Laravel-NextJS](https://github.com/laravel/breeze-next)

All login and backend functions work fine.

Here is some login

```
export const useAuthLaravel = ({ middleware } = {}) => {
    
    const router = useRouter()
    
    const { data: user, error, mutate } = useSWR('/api/user', () =>
        axios
            .get('/api/user')
            .then(res => res.data)
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status != 409) throw error

                router.push('/verify-email')
            }),

    )
    
    const csrf = () => axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')

    const login_laravel = async ({ setErrors, setStatus, ...props  }) => {

        await csrf()

        setErrors([])
        setStatus(null)

        axios
            .post('/login', props)
            .then(() => mutate())
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status != 422) throw error
                setErrors(Object.values(error.response.data.errors).flat())
            })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
            if (middleware == 'guest' && user) return user
            if (middleware == 'auth' && error && !user) logout_laravel()
        }, [user, error])

        return {
            user,
            csrf,
            login_laravel,
        }
    }
```

Now above returned values of `user` I am trying to put in AuthContext,

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useReducer, useState } from 'react';
import { authApi } from 'src/mocks/auth';


const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isInitialized: false,
  user: null
};

export const AuthProvider = (props) => {

  const { login_laravel, logout_laravel, user } = useAuthLaravel()

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialAuthState);

  useEffect(() => {   
        
    const initialize = async () => {

      try {
        if (user) {
          console.log('user exist')
          dispatch({
            type: 'INITIALIZE',
            payload: {
              isAuthenticated: true,
              user
            }
          });
        } else {
          console.log('user not exist')
          dispatch({
            type: 'INITIALIZE',
            payload: {
              isAuthenticated: false,
              user: null
            }
          });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        dispatch({
          type: 'INITIALIZE',
          payload: {
            isAuthenticated: false,
            user: null
          }
        });
      }
    };

    initialize();

  }, []);

  const login = async (email, password) => {

    try {
      const user = await login_laravel({ email, password, setErrors, setStatus });

      dispatch({
        type: 'LOGIN',
        isAuthenticated: true,
        payload: {
          user
        }
      });
   
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'LOGIN',
        payload: {
          isAuthenticated: false,
          user: null
        }
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...state,
        method: 'LARAVEL',
        login,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Now, when login function is run, it runs SWR validations, but when login finished, it does not return muted `user` back to `AuthProvider` function,

Does `useAuthLaravel` will run again after mutate and login function?

Thank you,

Not sure what sequence is getting wrong, any hints?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are trying to validate your user in `UseEffect` based on data from `useSWR`. These are "similar". My opinion is you need to modify `return function` for your page and not try to use validation in `useEffect`. *(useEffect and useSWR triggers on page load, useEffect can be loaded faster than useSWR)*

How I am doing this:

```
if (data){
        //trigger a function to validate your data
        return(
            <>
              <div>{something}</div>
            </>
            )
    }

if (error){
        //trigger a function to validate your data
        return (
            <div>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I am not sure it's what you are actually looking for. But I suggest you to do all data manipulations on the `backend side` or in `getServerSideProps` and not to load huge functions at the `front end` side. In perfect world you need to send fully fetched data to your `front end`.

Comment: Hi, i am fetching data in ```useAuthLaravel``` and return ```user``` to ```AuthProvider```, when the login function is clicked, it will revalidate ```user``` with mutate and then it should send revalidated ```user``` to ```AuthProvider```. In ```AuthProvider```, I am also checking ```user``` while loading page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you need the user who "just" logged in. You can even redirect them after logging in based on their user role. You can get the data from `/login` response since laravel returns the user data

I assume you are using [breeze-next](https://github.com/laravel/breeze-next/) based on your shared code

Inside `src/hooks/auth.js`

```
const login = async ({ setErrors, setStatus, ...props }) => {

    await csrf();

    setErrors([]);
    setStatus(null);

    const userJustLoggedIn = await axios
      .post("/login", props)
      .then(() => mutate())
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response.status !== 422) throw error;
        setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
      }).finally(function () {
        setLoading(false)
      })

      switch(userJustLoggedIn?.data?.role) {
        case 'admin':
          break;

        case 'role-1':
          break;

        case 'role-2':
          window.location.replace(`${window.location.origin}/role-2/dashboard`);
          break;
      }
  };
```